# Should I add database constraints for null false and width if I have validations for these?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, constraints

When should I add database constraints if I already have validations that do the same thing?

I am aware that if something is mission critical for your app like making sure an email address used for user authentication is unique that you would indeed want a database index with a unique constraint. It is the non mission critical fields I have the question about.

For instance if I have an articles table with a field for title I will have a constraint in the model that prevents blank title submissions.

```
# app/models/article.rb
validates :title, presence: true
```

Is it a best practice to also add a null false constraint to the database? If somehow a blank title gets past the model validation it is not a mission critical problem.

Maximum length is a similar question. I can also set a maximum length validation in the article model that will prevent a title of over 100 characters.

```
# app/models/article.rb
validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
```

By default Postgres will set the maximum length of a varchar field (string type in Rails) to 255. If an overly long title somehow gets past the validation it's not a mission critical problem so is there a performance benefit of setting width constraint in the database to 100 characters? Or what about if it was for a 2 character state_code? Is there a best practice for setting a shorter width in the database than the default if a model validation will prevent it?

And I'm adding an HTML attribute in the form fields to check for presence and maxlength so there would be potentially three checks on the same input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends and opinions vary.  I tend to favor always having constraints in the database even if the code validates it.  For the reason that developers, QA, etc. may attempt to inject data directly into the database.  Having a constraint enforces the convention.  See this [Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39833/why-are-constraints-applied-in-the-database-rather-than-the-code) thread for more feedback.